# Blobstore fo App Engine is free for api call?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, datastore

Datastore is very exspensive because of read/write ops price (not storing price).
But I don't see any price for Memcache and Blobstore API calls price.
Is it free or not ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [billing doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing) says: with Blobstore there is no per API call cost, but you pay for the storage ($0.026/month). On top of that there is the standard $0.12/Gb traffic cost, which you pay for all traffic.

Comment: If you don't have billing enabled, can you still use Blobstore within the limitations of the quotas?